# How to send an empty array from JS to PHP using JSON?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Is it possible to send an empty array to PHP from JS using JSON?

```
<?
if ($_GET['test']) {
    $data = $_GET['data'];
    print_r($data);
    exit;
}
?>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('temp.php', {
        "test": 1,
        "data": []
    })
</script>
```

This is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do. Basically, I'm sending data to PHP so it can update the database. If I send an empty array, it should save an empty array. However, in the above example, only "test" gets passed and "data" gets thrown away. The only solution I can think of is to do something sloppy, like this:

```
if (! isset($data = $_GET['data']))
    $data = array();
```

So, I'm basically just making an empty array after JSON/JS throws it away. Unless there's another way? Thank you!

Comment: It's not sloppy to use default values/objects in place of missing GET/POST params. It's very good practice!

Comment: I agree, but sometimes the empty array _is_ data. The array defines the number of selections made an empty array means no selections have been made yet.

Comment: Then that's precisely the assumption to make server-side when the param is missing.

Comment: I guess if someone wants to say that it's not possible, I'll accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON('temp.php', {
    "test": 1,
    "data": JSON.stringify([])
})
```